# Expand Grouped Data using shell or perl

Tags: performance, bash, perl

I have a log file that is grouping http requests in 5 minute increments based on a unique set of characteristics.  Format is as follows:

beginTime endTime platform hostname osVersion os requestType httpStatus nbInstances

So a sample log line could be:

1423983600 1423983900 platform1 test01 8.1 win createAcct 200 15

This indicates in that 5 minute timeframe there were 15 requests with this unique attribute set.  What I would like to do is then take this and generate 15 lines identical lines in an output file.

Right now I have a very simple script that is getting the job done but probably not very efficient:

```
#!/bin/bash

file=$1
count=0
cat $file | while read line
do
string=`echo $line | awk '{print $1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6,$7,$8}'`
nbInst=`echo $line | awk '{print $9}'`
while [[ $count -lt $nbInst ]]
do
echo "$string" >> test_data.log
count=`expr $count + 1`
done
count=0
done
```

Any ideas on a faster solution in bash or perl?  Thanks.

Comment: Why are you trying to de-summarise your data like this? That might help give a solution. Algorithmically, you'd be doing much the same in perl.

Comment: We are summarizing the data in these 5 minute groups to reduce network load as we transfer to our internal servers.  Once we have the data in our internal servers we want to index using ELK so that we can graph it and it would be preferable to have 1 log line equal 1 event, which the grouped data does not do.

Comment: OK. That sound like an XY problem to me - I don't know a great deal about the subject, but would be very surprised to find that a database can't cope with event coalescing at least as well as a script can. But I'll knock up something perlish anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments - it seems unusual that you need to de-coalesce your events to process and index.

However this should do what you're asking:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

#uses DATA segment from below as file. You'll probably want either STDIN
#or open a file handle. 
while (<DATA>) {
    #separate line on whitespace
    my @line = split;
    #grab the last element of the line (pop returns the value, and removes
    #from the list)
    for ( 1 .. pop(@line) ) {
        print join( " ", @line ), "\n";
    }
}

__DATA__
1423983600 1423983900 platform1 test01 8.1 win createAcct 200 15
```

Comment: Your perl script is infinitely faster than my bash script.  I appreciate you taking the time to help me even if you might not think my question is valid.

Comment: One of the downsides of working with shell is there's an overhead to starting other programs (like awk) repeatedly.